# C++11 Sharing the same function with different types of random distributions

Tags: c++, c++11

I have two functions. The only difference of these two functions is that they are using different random number generators. For your convenient, I wrote some compilable codes as below. The two functions are

> fillRandomVecInt

and

> fillRandomVecNorm

How can we combine these two functions as one? Can I use a pointer pointing to the base class and dynamically hook up `rnorm` and `runifInt`? or use template to resolve this issue? Many thanks for your help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<random>
using namespace std;

class RandomVec{
private:
    unsigned seed = 0;
    std::default_random_engine generator{seed};
    std::normal_distribution<> rnorm{0,1};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> runifInt{0,1};
public:

    void fillRandomVecInt(vector<int> & v);
    void fillRandomVecNorm(vector<double> & v);
};

void RandomVec::fillRandomVecNorm(vector<double> &v) {
    for(auto i=v.begin();i!=v.end();++i){
        *i=rnorm(generator);
    }
}

void RandomVec::fillRandomVecInt(vector<int> &v) {
    for(auto i=v.begin();i!=v.end();++i){
        *i=runifInt(generator);
    }
}


int main() {
    RandomVec rv;
    vector<double> x=vector<double>(10);
    rv.fillRandomVecNorm(x);
    vector<int> y = vector<int>(10);
    rv.fillRandomVecInt(y);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll suggest to use template specialization.

```
class RandomVec {
private:
  unsigned seed = 0;
  std::default_random_engine generator{seed};
  std::normal_distribution<> rnorm{0, 1};
  std::uniform_int_distribution<> runifInt{0, 1};

  template<typename T>
  T generateRandom(void);

public:
  template<typename T>
  void fillRandomVec(vector<T> &v);
};

template<>
int RandomVec::generateRandom(void) {
  return runifInt(generator);
}

template<>
double RandomVec::generateRandom(void) {
  return rnorm(generator);
}

template<typename T>
void RandomVec::fillRandomVec(vector<T> &v) {
  for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i) {
    *i = generateRandom<T>();
  }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful solution!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am misunderstanding what you are asking, but couldn’t you just use function overloading?

```
void fillRandomVec(vector<int>& v) {
    //code...
}

void fillRandomVec(vector<double>& v {
    //code...
}
```

Or...

```
//this is a function I have used that I copied in
template<class T>
bool vectIsInt(std::vector<T>& v)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        if (v[i] != floor(v[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

template<class U>
void fillRandomVec(std::vector<U>& v)
{
    if (vectIsInt(v))
    {
        //code if int vect
    }
    else
    {
        //code if double vect...
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a solution, but I feel that overloading may not be efficient when I have many functions with similar structures. Say in each function I have 50 lines of code and I have 20 of such functions. The only difference of each function is using different random number generator. Can we make the codes more elegant?

Comment: Ah I understand. Well you could use templates or you could you make a single function that tests for what was inputted if you don’t want to mess with templates.

Comment: but strategy pattern require a common interface, and it seems that the random number didn't have a base class. Any simple solution?

Comment: It seems not work in that way, because we also need to change rnorm and runifInt within the function based on T. How can we do that?

Comment: Sorry I wasn’t done yet. I also don’t have access to a computer at the moment so I didn’t get to test the code so excuse any errors. @drbombe

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<time.h>
#include<algorithm>
#include<functional>
#include <iostream>
#include<random>
using namespace std;

namespace stackoverflow
{
    //just for this topic

    template<typename _FwdIt,typename _RngFn>
    void random_fill(_FwdIt first, _FwdIt last, _RngFn&& fn)
    {   //random fill the range [first,last) by means of fn
        _DEBUG_RANGE(first, last);
        generate(first, last, fn);
    }
}

//random function-fn is provided by yourself, for example

int main() {
    using namespace stackoverflow;

    static default_random_engine e(time(0));
    std::normal_distribution<> rnorm{ 0,1 };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> runifInt{ 0,1 };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> runifInt_1{ 2,10 };
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> runifDouble{ 0,1 };

    vector<int> x(10);
    //type int can be random fill throw normal or uniform distribution or other, and 
    //some distribution parameter can change
    random_fill(x.begin(), x.end(), bind(ref(runifInt),ref(e)));
    random_fill(x.begin(), x.end(), bind(ref(runifInt_1), ref(e)));
    random_fill(x.begin(), x.end(), bind(ref(rnorm), ref(e)));

    vector<double> y(10);
    //type double can be random fill throw normal or uniform distribution or other, and
    //some distribution parameter can change
    random_fill(y.begin(), y.end(), bind(ref(rnorm),ref(e)));
    random_fill(y.begin(), y.end(), bind(ref(runifDouble), ref(e)));

    return 0;
}
```

I think STL algorithm is the most helpful, So I design these mutating STL. 
  For the object defined in the main function you can move them into the stackoverflow namespace as you like, but don't them global.

Comment: But this solution is essentially a function overload. Using overloading could be easier, right?

Comment: right,using overloading is more eaiser. So  I change the code by template overloading. I mutate the STL style to gain flexible and scalable.

Answer (score 0):

You can template a base class whose specialization provides a different distribution object according to its typename parameter.

Then, for every type that you want to support, only a small amount of code that specializes the class template with the corresponding distribution object is needed.

One advantage of this approach is that one specialized base class can support multiple `typename T`. For example, in the example below, all integral (not just `int`) and floating-point (not just `double`) types are supported.

See the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<random>
using namespace std;

namespace {
// Helper type defined since C++14.
template<bool B, class T = void>
using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<B,T>::type;
}

// Base class to be specialized with different distribution object.
template<typename T, typename Enable = void>
class RandomVecBase;

// Supports integers with uniform_int_distribution
template<typename T>
class RandomVecBase<T, enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value> > {
 public:
  RandomVecBase() : distrib_{0, 1} {}
 protected:
  uniform_int_distribution<> distrib_;
};

// Supports floating-point with normal_distribution.
template<typename T>
class RandomVecBase<T, enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value> > {
 public:
  RandomVecBase() : distrib_{0, 1} {}
 protected:
  normal_distribution<> distrib_;
};

// Actual class, code in fillRandomVec() only needs to be written once
template<typename T>
class RandomVec : public RandomVecBase<T> {
 private:
  unsigned seed = 0;
  default_random_engine generator{seed};

 public:
  void fillRandomVec(vector<T>& v) {
    for (auto& i : v) {
      i = this->distrib_(generator);
    }
  }
};


int main() {
  RandomVec<double> rv_double;
  vector<double> x = vector<double>(10);
  rv_double.fillRandomVec(x);

  RandomVec<int> rv_int;
  vector<int> y = vector<int>(10);
  rv_int.fillRandomVec(y);
  return 0;
}
```